# Alcatel Onetouch Idol S malfunctioning battery

Tags: battery, alcatel-one-touch-idol-s

My battery on my Alcatel Onetouch Idol S (running Android 4.2.2) is behaving oddly. It will discharge normally, then all of a sudden go from 55% to flat (0%) in seconds. I would put it down to finally rooting it, but I have no cold evidence to prove it. Does anybody know how it can be fixed, or how to figure out why it is happening?

Additional info:

- I believe the CPU governor should be set to `ondemand`
- It was rooted via KingRoot v4.6.0 132, and the KingRoot kernel version is 4.6.0 47
- The SU version is 3.54

Comment: How old is your battery?  You can try the steps in accepted answer here and then my solution, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128091/android-dies-at-20-battery/128108#128108

Comment: @beeshyams The battery is about a month old. Literally a month. Oh, i will try the second method on that link, but it is the only one i can do at home. There is a irremovable back (though the manufacturers can take it off)

Comment: Curious as to what happened when you tried steps in earlier suggestion

Comment: @beeshyams It worked, kinda. My phone did not turn on. Charged it to find it was drained,  and it had a normal discharge when booted. I done that about a day ago.

Comment: Good. Hope it gets to be normal