# Nexus 5 battery drain - dropping from 50% to zero instantly Marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: nexus-5, battery-life, 6.0-marshmallow

I've been having some problems with the WiFi drain issue that some others have posted on here, but yesterday I had a new problem with my battery which may be related but may be entirely different.
My battery was around 50% when the phone suddenly switched off (first time this has ever happened). When I switched it back on, battery was at 1%. I tried to quickly finish what I was doing (Uber app) expecting the phone to turn off again, but it didn't. I looked at the battery and it had gone up to 5%. About 15 mins later it was up to 20% and climbing, as if it was on charge. 
Today around the same time it happened again, but I wasn't using Uber.
I can't see how to post screenshots, sorry all new to this forum!

Comment: Nexus phones have battery reset logic procedure. As explained here https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/D7er7nMbzHI
and http://android.stackexchange.com/a/129529/131553. Try doing that and let me know if it worked to convert into answer

Comment: @beeshyams It sounds like there are multiple issues being reported in that thread. It also appears that there is a hardware issue for many people. I am interested in knowing what works for the OP

Comment: @user1354557: I am not sure, not having the specific device-hence posted as a suggestion

Comment: Having the same problem, and pretty sure it's software related. Generally more specific in my case, drops from 15% to 0, then if I plug in a charger it jumps to 15% again.